# Matrix Toggle Issue

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a matrix with six row groups, when I add a toggle to expand the data on them it works fine unless I toggle on the last one. It will appear fine in the preview but when I try to expand all it does is change the plus to a minus. It works fine on export to excel but wont work previewed or viewed in a web page. Any suggestions?